# How to get APNs deviceToken from KMP-Multiplatform

Tags: apple-push-notifications, token, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I am using Compose Multiplatform to develop a mobile app, and I need to obtain the Apple APNs token to submit it to the server. I have been searching for examples, and I found that in Swift, you can write the following code in the AppDelegate to get the token:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print("\(token)")
    }
```

and my ios main fun:

```
    @main
    struct iOSApp: App {
    
    init() {
        HelperKt.doInitKoin()
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    }
```

However, I need guidance on how to achieve this in kotlin Multiplatform.

I have written the following code in Kotlin for registration APNs.

```
    actual suspend fun fetchNotifyToken(tokenFun: (String) -> Unit) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

```
    class AppDelegate : UIResponder(), UIApplicationDelegateProtocol{
        override fun application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: Map<Any?, *>?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    
    
        override fun application(
            application: UIApplication,
            didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: NSData
        ) {
            //token here
            println(didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken)
    
        }
    
        companion object : UIResponderMeta(),
            UIApplicationDelegateProtocolMeta
    }
```

How do I write code so that AppDelegate is called correctly and gets the token value?